# Trying to compare a button's background with none with js

Tags: javascript, html

So, I'm trying to make a tic tac toe game. the board is made with buttons so everytime you click on one it changes the background to a circle or whatever. There's a function that checks after every turn if someone won by comparing backgrounds. This function says that if background in 1st button is the same as the 2nd and 2nd is the same as 3rd executes window.alert("GAME OVER"). But it gets executed every single time i start it because all backgrounds are started with none value so they are all the same, that is why i need to compare them and to make sure the have a cross/circle.

All buttons backgrounds are background:none; with css

this function changes the background of the buttons

```html
function mark(id){
    var e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9;
    if(turn % 2 == 1){
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundImage = "url('cruz.webp')";
        
    }else if (turn % 2 == 0){
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundImage = "url('circulo.webp')";
       
    }
    turno();
   
    check();
    
    cambiaturn();
}
```

This function prueba checks if someone won after every move

```html
function prueba(){

    

        if(document.getElementById('id1').style.backgroundImage === document.getElementById('id2').style.backgroundImage && document.getElementById('id2').style.backgroundImage === document.getElementById('id3').style.backgroundImage && document.getElementById('id3').style.backgroundImage !== document.style.backgroundImage=none){
            window.alert("GAME OVER1")
            } 
        else if(document.getElementById('id1').style.backgroundImage === document.getElementById('id5').style.backgroundImage && document.getElementById('id5').style.backgroundImage === document.getElementById('id9').style.backgroundImage && document.getElementById('id9').style.backgroundImage !== document.style.backgroundImage=none){
            window.alert("GAME OVER2")
            } 
        else if (document.getElementById('id1').style.backgroundImage === document.getElementById('id4').style.backgroundImage && document.getElementById('id4').style.backgroundImage === document.getElementById('id7').style.backgroundImage && document.getElementById('id7').style.backgroundImage !== document.style.backgroundImage=none){
            window.alert("GAME OVER7")
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('id2').style.backgroundImage === document.getElementById('id5').style.backgroundImage && document.getElementById('id5').style.backgroundImage === document.getElementById('id8').style.backgroundImage && document.getElementById('id8').style.backgroundImage !== document.style.backgroundImage=none){
            window.alert("GAME OVER8")
                }
         else if (document.getElementById('id3').style.backgroundImage === document.getElementById('id5').style.backgroundImage && document.getElementById('id5').style.backgroundImage === document.getElementById('id7').style.backgroundImage && document.getElementById('id7').style.backgroundImage !== document.style.backgroundImage=none){
                window.alert("GAME OVER6")
            } 
        else if (document.getElementById('id4').style.backgroundImage === document.getElementById('id5').style.backgroundImage  && document.getElementById('id5').style.backgroundImage === document.getElementById('id6').style.backgroundImage && document.getElementById('id6').style.backgroundImage !== document.style.backgroundImage=none){
                window.alert("GAME OVER3")
            } 
            
        else if (document.getElementById('id7').style.backgroundImage === document.getElementById('id8').style.backgroundImage && document.getElementById('id8').style.backgroundImage === document.getElementById('id9').style.backgroundImage && document.getElementById('id9').style.backgroundImage !== document.style.backgroundImage=none){
            window.alert("GAME OVER4")
        } 
        else if (document.getElementById('id3').style.backgroundImage === document.getElementById('id6').style.backgroundImage && document.getElementById('id6').style.backgroundImage === document.getElementById('id9').style.backgroundImage && document.getElementById('id9').style.backgroundImage !== document.style.backgroundImage=none){
            window.alert("GAME OVER5")
        } 
        
    }
```

This is the html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <link href="stylejuego.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ta Te Ti</title>
</head>
<body>
     
    <h1 id="titulo">Ta Te Ti</h1>
    <h2 id="turno">Turno del jugador:  </h2>
    <div id="background">

        <div class="botones">   

            <button id="id1" style="margin: 17px;" onclick="mark(this.id)"   >  </button>
            <button id="id2" style="margin: 10px;" onclick="mark(this.id)"  >  </button>
            <button id="id3" style="margin: 10px;" onclick="mark(this.id)"  >  </button><br>
            <button id="id4" style="margin: 17px;" onclick="mark(this.id)"  >  </button>
            <button id="id5" style="margin: 10px;" onclick="mark(this.id)"  >  </button>
            <button id="id6" style="margin: 10px;" onclick="mark(this.id)"  >  </button><br> 
            <button id="id7" style="margin: 17px;" onclick="mark(this.id)"  >  </button>
            <button id="id8" style="margin: 10px;" onclick="mark(this.id)"  >  </button>
            <button id="id9" style="margin: 10px;" onclick="mark(this.id)"  >  </button>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please provide a functional code so we can replicate your issue.

Comment: This code is not functional. Provide a functional code to replicate yor problem.

Comment: I have noticed a bug, ``none`` is a css value, to compare it in javascript you have to use ``"none"``, not ``none``. In spanish: He notado un error, ``none`` es un valor css, para compararlo en javascript tienes que usar ``"none"``, no ``none``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had to be compared to = ' ';

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the onclick event and checking the body background.

```js
function check(elem) {
  if(elem.style.background == 'none') {
    elem.innerText = 'No';
  } else {
    elem.innerText = 'Bg';
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="check(this);" id="id" style="height: 35px; width: 35px; background: none;">
  &nbsp;
</button>

<button onclick="check(this);" id="id" style="height: 35px; width: 35px; background: green;">
  &nbsp;
</button>
```

This code checks whether the element clicked has a background or not, and warns you if it does or does not when you click it.